# visual studio host stopping sometimes and marshal objective throwing error some times when we save notepad to desktop folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

***This is code to `save untitled notepad to desktop or given path`. when we run this code visual studio host stopping some times and some times `marshal object throwing error`, when we have more than one notepad opened some files are saving .. after that program stopping automatically.. we are passing path as Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop***

```
Private Const WM_GETTEXT As Integer = &HD
    Private Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As Integer = &HE
    Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, _
    ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, _
                                     ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, _
                                     ByVal lclassName As String, _
                                     ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    Sub saveNotepad(pat As String)
        Try
            Dim processes() As Process
            Dim procName As String = "notepad"
            processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName)
            If processes IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each proc In processes
                    If Not proc.MainWindowTitle = "" Then

                        Dim Hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, proc.MainWindowTitle)

                        Dim ChildHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", Nothing)
                        Dim size As Int32 = SendMessage(CInt(ChildHandle), WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0).ToInt32()

                        Dim Hndl As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size + 1)
                        Dim NumText As Integer = SendMessage(ChildHandle, WM_GETTEXT, size + 1, Hndl)

                        Dim Text As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Hndl)

                        Dim savePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(pat, "Terminator")
                        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(IO.Path.Combine(savePath, proc.MainWindowTitle & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")) & ".txt")

                        Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(Text)
                        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
                        fs.Close()
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Hndl)

                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Common.LogDebuggerData("Error: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Does it give you an error message? Are you checking the return value of `FindWindow` and any other Windows API calls? Is it possible that `proc.MainWindowTitle` contains characters that are not valid file name characters? Have you run this in the debugger and noted on which line you get the error? You need to give us more information if you want help debugging this.

Comment: take Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop as path (method parameter ) . I have added api calls also please check it once.. proc.MainWindowTitle we getting name of untitled notepad not data ... FindWindowEx find edit the control of running notepad...Marshal.AllocHGlobal is the mentod will Alloc memory for the buffer that receives the text

Comment: Your code corrupts the global heap, random misery is the expected outcome.  A Unicode char takes 2 bytes so it must be Marshal.AllocHGlobal(2 * (size + 1))

Comment: Thanks hans-passant   ... Working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing

```
Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size + 1)
```

with

```
Marshal.AllocHGlobal(2 * (size + 1))
```

will solve the problem